# IF type of statement in SELECT

Tags: sql

wondering if there is a way do this kind of if in SELECT block.

```
SELECT
   [  if Table1.field == NULL 
      then
         Table2.field
      else
         Table3.field
   ] as OutputField
```

i checked the IFF and CASE-WHEN, doesn't seem to support this.

Comment: You've checked `CASE WHEN`? Really? Show that attempt.

Comment: What is your database?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `IS` for `NULL` checks:

```
select case when Table1.field IS NULL 
            then Table2.field
            else Table3.field
       end as OutputField
from ...
```

Answer (score 1):

On MS Access database, you would use `IIF` along with `ISNULL`:

```
SELECT
    IIF(ISNULL(Table1.Field), Table2.Field, Table3.Field) AS OutputField
FROM yourTable
```